# prevent main container stretching above 1680px using css media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Can anyone help with this problem I have?

I have been designing a fluid-responsive website but I need to constrain the width of the main container above 1680px (Most Mac screens) as anything above this size makes the site become over stretched.

I've tried setting the main container like so:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 1.0%!important;
  padding-right: 1.0%!important;
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 1680px;
}
```

The trouble with this is main content area of the site doesn't remain in the center of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `margin: auto;` to your .container-fluid element. That should get it centered on large displays.